# Specific list manipulation

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose I have two lists each of different sizes, e.g. toy case `ListX = {x1, x2, x3}` and `ListY = {y1, y2}` and all possible combinations of elements give rise to an element in another list `ListZ = {z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6}` of length `Length[ListX]` $ \times $ `Length[ListY]`, i.e the tuple `(x1, y1)` is associated with `z1`, say.

How to merge all three lists such that I obtain the following combined list?

```
{{{x1, y1}, z1}, {{x1, y2}, z2}, {{x2, y1}, z3}, 
 {{x2, y2}, z4}, {{x3, y1}, z5}, {{x3, y2}, z6}}
```

I've tried nested tables but I always generate additional items that I don't want. The actual lists I'm dealing with are of length O(50) such that the equivalent of `ListZ` is of length O(2500).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do what you are looking for:

```
ListX = {x1, x2, x3};
ListY = {y1, y2};
ListZ = {z1, z2, z3, z4, z5, z6};
Partition[Riffle[Flatten[Outer[List, ListX, ListY], 1], ListZ], 2]
```

The Outer product gives all the pairs, but they are nested funny so you need to Flatten. Riffle does the interleaving of the Outer product with ListZ, and again it's not quite got your desired structure, but Partition fixes that.

Answer (score 9):

```
Transpose@{Tuples@{ListX, ListY}, ListZ}
```

Comment: Very nice solution! You can also use `Thread` instead of `Transpose`:`Thread@{Tuples@{ListX, ListY}, ListZ}`

Comment: Yes. Thanks for reminding me that.